# How to place 2 views to the bottom of the parent but one stacked above the other?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

In a `RelativeLayout` if a view has `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true”` then it is placed to the bottom of the parent.
If 2 views have `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true”` then both are placed on the bottom, but 1 **above** the other.
How can I have 2 view to have the setting `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true”` and one to be stacked over the other?
`android:layout_above` seems to be not applicable/working for this case.

Comment: Set margin for View to be stacked above with `android:layout_marginbottom = Height of bottom most Element`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the views inside a LinearLayout with `orientation - vertical`, and put

```
layout_alignParentBottom=true
```

To the LinearLayout;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/red"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

They won't be placed one after another if you have set only `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true”`. Please paste your layout xml so that the real issue can be found.

Answer (score 0):

`layout_above` means "above" in a Y direction, not in a Z direction, if that makes sense. If you want them to overlay, remove the `layout_above` attribute and make them both `layout_alignParentBottom=true`.